# UITableView method tableView:didEndDisplayingFooterView: isn't getting called

Tags: ios, uitableview

The following method won't get called when I scroll the tableView far enough so that it scrolls out of bounds.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that any UITextFields or UITextViews are not displaying their keyboards.

You can call:

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

If any textField or textView is the firstResponder of the responder chain, the UITableView will not call the `didEndDisplayingFooterView:` method

Comment: This is not necessarily the *only* reason the above might happen, but merely one phenonmenon I have observed.